# Lex: a small program to count words in the input

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, yacc, lex

I'm extremely new to Lex and the complete requirement of this problem is as follows:

> Write a Lex input file that will produce a program that counts
>   characters, words, and lines in a text file and reports the counts.
>   Define a word to be any sequence of letters and/or digits, without
>   punctuation or spaces. Punctuation and white space do not count as
>   words.

Now I've written down the code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int cno = 0, wno = 0, lno = 0; /*counts of characters, words and lines */
%}
character [a-z]
digit [0-9]
word ({character}|{digit})+[^({character}|{digit})]
line \n
%%
{line} { lno++; REJECT; }
{word} { wno++; REJECT; }
{character} { cno++; }
%%
void main()
{ yylex();
  fprintf(stderr, "Number of characters: %d; Number of words: %d; Number of lines: %d\n", cno, wno, lno);
  return;
}
```

I tested it with the text file:

```
this is line #1
line #2 is here
!@#$%^&*()
haha hey hey
```

And I got the output

```
   #1
 #2  
!@#$%^&*()

Number of characters: 30; Number of words: 45; Number of lines: 4
```

But the correct output should be

```
Number of characters: 30; Number of words: 11; Number of lines: 4
```

I guess the error of "number of words" should be somehow due to every count of characters, so how should I modify my program to tackle with this?

Also, there're some unnecessary output coming out (those punctuations). How should I modify my program to avoid them?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a rule to deal with 'uninteresting' characters; you still need to count them.

You don't want to reject newlines.

You don't need the trailing context on the definition of `word`.  You should probably include capital letters as `character`.

This seems to work:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int cno = 0, wno = 0, lno = 0; /*counts of characters, words and lines */
%}

character [a-zA-Z]
digit [0-9]
word ({character}|{digit})+
line \n

%%

{line} { cno++; lno++; }
{word} { wno++; cno += strlen(yytext); }
. { cno++; }

%%

int main(void)
{
    yylex();
    printf("Number of characters: %d; ", cno);
    printf("Number of words:      %d; ", wno);
    printf("Number of lines:      %d\n", lno);
    return 0;
}
```

When run on its own source code, the output was:

```
Number of characters: 463; Number of words:      65; Number of lines:      27
```

The standard `wc` command (which has a different definition of 'word') yields:

```
  27      73     463 xyz.l
```

This agrees on the number of lines and characters.

Comment: Thank you. There are some small misunderstandings of the requirement in your code but I've figured them out and I think I've come up with the correct code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmmm...so you don't count characters that are not in words?  The character count is the alphabetic characters in the words, not the punctuation and newlines and so on?  But digits, while they're part of a word, do not count as characters?  Interesting definitions; not immediately obvious from the question.  But with those definitions and your sample data, you can end up with the 'right answer'.

Comment: You can also make use of lex internal variable yyleng instead of using strlen().